# SQL Server : improve performance of inner query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to improve the performance of my query by reducing the inner queries.

I will need the first one as it returns the ReasonTUM.

However, I would like to use a case with the ReasonTUM so that it returns a number as well.

How can I achieve this? I've tried referencing `mms.sMachineStateName` in the original query but it doesn't detect the column.

The only other way I can think of is to use another sub query but this is taking about 1min to return 300 rows due to the joins.

```
declare @ReportingStart datetime = '20160917 07:00'
declare @ReportingEnd datetime = '20160918 07:00'

SELECT 
      [sWorkcellDescription]
      ,[tStart]
      ,[dDurationSeconds]/60 as Duration_m
      ,[sStateDescription]
      ,datepart(hh,tstart) as myHr
      ,case when convert(time,tstart)< '07:00' then dateadd(dd,-1,convert(date,tstart)) else convert(date,tstart) end as myDate,
        cast(dateadd(hour,datepart(hh,tstart),0) as datetime) as dispTime,
        (
            select top 1 mms.sMachineStateName
            from OEEEvent oe
            inner join RSBizWare.dbo.OEEConfigEvent ce on oe.lOEEConfigEventId = ce.lOEEConfigEventId
            inner join RSBizWare.dbo.OEELOVCodeVal rs on oe.sStartVal = rs.sDescription and ce.lOEEIntRSSqlId=rs.lOEELOVCodeId
            inner join RSBizWare.dbo.OEEStateConfig mms on rs.lMachineState = mms.lOEEStateConfigId
            where qq.tStart between oe.tStart and oe.tEnd and oe.sPartId='Ore-Hoist'
            order by qq.tStart asc
        ) as ReasonTUM,
                (
            select top 1 case
        when mms.sMachineStateName = 'Production' then '1' 
        when mms.sMachineStateName = 'Unscheduled Production' then '2'
        when mms.sMachineStateName = 'Idle time' then '3'
        when mms.sMachineStateName = 'Opportune Maintenance' then '4'
        when mms.sMachineStateName = 'Planned External Downtime' then '5'
        when mms.sMachineStateName = 'Planned External Downtime' then '5'
        when mms.sMachineStateName = 'Planned Maintenance Mechanical' then '5'
        when mms.sMachineStateName = 'Planned Maintenance Electrical' then '6'
        when mms.sMachineStateName = 'Unplanned Downtime Operational' then '7'
        when mms.sMachineStateName = 'Unplanned Downtime Mechanical' then '8'
        when mms.sMachineStateName = 'Unplanned Downtime Electrical' then '9'
        else '99' end
            from OEEEvent oe
            inner join RSBizWare.dbo.OEEConfigEvent ce on oe.lOEEConfigEventId = ce.lOEEConfigEventId
            inner join RSBizWare.dbo.OEELOVCodeVal rs on oe.sStartVal = rs.sDescription and ce.lOEEIntRSSqlId=rs.lOEELOVCodeId
            inner join RSBizWare.dbo.OEEStateConfig mms on rs.lMachineState = mms.lOEEStateConfigId
            where qq.tStart between oe.tStart and oe.tEnd and oe.sPartId='Ore-Hoist'
        ) as rank
FROM 
    [RSBizWare].[dbo].[OEEQStateData] qq
WHERE 
    (tstart >= @ReportingStart AND tStart < @ReportingEnd) 
    AND sWorkcellDescription = 'Hoisting' 
    AND dDurationSeconds > 5
ORDER BY
    tStart ASC
```

Comment: How does the inner query relate to the outer? JOINs are generally only slow if 1) they cannot be executed as a set [an easy way to reason they can/are executed as such is to turn the inner queries into JOINs themselves] or 2) they are missing appropriate indices for the query.

Comment: read execution plan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `OUTER APPLY` to avoid calling the `sub-query` twice

```
SELECT [sworkcelldescription], 
       [tstart], 
       [ddurationseconds] / 60                                  AS Duration_m, 
       [sstatedescription], 
       Datepart(hh, tstart)                                     AS myHr, 
       CASE 
         WHEN CONVERT(TIME, tstart) < '07:00' THEN Dateadd(dd, -1, 
                                                   CONVERT(DATE, tstart 
                                                   )) 
         ELSE CONVERT(DATE, tstart) 
       END                                                      AS myDate, 
       Cast(Dateadd(hour, Datepart(hh, tstart), 0) AS DATETIME) AS dispTime, 
       OA.reasontum, 
       OA.[rank] 
FROM   [RSBizWare].[dbo].[oeeqstatedata] qq 
       OUTER apply (SELECT TOP 1 mms.smachinestatename, 
                                 CASE mms.smachinestatename 
                                   WHEN 'Production' THEN '1' 
                                   WHEN 'Unscheduled Production' THEN '2' 
                                   WHEN 'Idle time' THEN '3' 
                                   WHEN 'Opportune Maintenance' THEN '4' 
                                   WHEN 'Planned External Downtime' THEN '5' 
                                   WHEN 'Planned External Downtime' THEN '5' 
                                   WHEN 'Planned Maintenance Mechanical' THEN '5' 
                                   WHEN 'Planned Maintenance Electrical' THEN '6' 
                                   WHEN 'Unplanned Downtime Operational' THEN '7' 
                                   WHEN 'Unplanned Downtime Mechanical' THEN '8' 
                                   WHEN 'Unplanned Downtime Electrical' THEN '9' 
                                   ELSE '99' 
                                 END AS [Rank] 
                    FROM   oeeevent oe 
                           INNER JOIN rsbizware.dbo.oeeconfigevent ce 
                                   ON oe.loeeconfigeventid = 
                                      ce.loeeconfigeventid 
                           INNER JOIN rsbizware.dbo.oeelovcodeval rs 
                                   ON oe.sstartval = rs.sdescription 
                                      AND ce.loeeintrssqlid = rs.loeelovcodeid 
                           INNER JOIN rsbizware.dbo.oeestateconfig mms 
                                   ON rs.lmachinestate = mms.loeestateconfigid 
                    WHERE  qq.tstart BETWEEN oe.tstart AND oe.tend 
                           AND oe.spartid = 'Ore-Hoist' 
                    ORDER  BY qq.tstart ASC) OA 
WHERE  ( tstart >= @ReportingStart 
         AND tstart < @ReportingEnd ) 
       AND sworkcelldescription = 'Hoisting' 
       AND ddurationseconds > 5 
ORDER  BY tstart ASC
```

Comment: In the question both queries selecting record using TOP 1 where 1 with ORDER BY and another without but in your way both values selected using ORDER BY,  if both result needed in same order then its fine otherwise is it return the same result ??

Comment: @Suraz - If am not wrong OP wants Order by in both the sub-queries

Comment: @Prdp - query performance went from 59s to 28s! Thank you very much

Comment: @Prdp It means you are right so that +1, it's the good technique to avoid subqueries.

Comment: @Suraz It's not okay to omit an ORDER BY if you care about which record you want at the top of the result set. Sql Server can and will change that on you behind the scenes in certain cases. Thus, if there is no ORDER BY, _any_ of the returned records is okay.